# Can there be situations where both "saber" and "conocer" can be used?

Tags: definiciones, verbos, sinónimos

Example 1

> Uds quieren saber mi país.

If `concur` is substituted for `saber` in this sentence, the meaning switch from knowing exactly what the country is to things about the country.

Example 2

> Conozco los servicios que ofrece aquella oficina.

If `saber` is used instead, then **I** know what *exactly* what service they offer.

**PS** THE EXAMPLES ARE WHAT ARE SAID TO BE CORRECT BY MY TEACHER.

Answer (score 4):

`Saber` and `conocer` are not always perfectly interchangeable.

`Saber` is used when we want to convey knowledge or mastery of skills. `Conocer` conveys a meaning more like "be familiar with" or "to know".

First example is incorrect. It needs a preposition

> Uds. quieren saber **de** mi país.

Which conveys, "you want to gather information about my country", rather than "you want to know my country" (like, visit for the first time), which would be

> Uds. quieren conocer mi país.  <sub>(you want to visit the country, or learn about it)</sub>

For the second example, you could use either `saber` or `conocer` and meaning would not change much. `Saber` would imply that you know the services, but `conocer` would convey that you have a deeper understanding of them.

Comment: I agree with all, but I doubt about your correction on the first example. I guess Doeser could mean "Ustedes quieren saber (cuál es) mi país", meaning where I am from.

Comment: What is the difference between gathering info. and learning about something?

Comment: Sometimes I felt "saber de" and "conocer" are the same. Both mean "to know about".

Comment: Saber + verb = to know how to + verb (like saber cocinar = know how to cook, saber conducir = know how to drive); here "conocer" is not appropriate. Conocer + a person or a place = meet + persons/places; here "saber" is not appropriate.

Comment: Saber + de + somebody/someplace = to get news about somebody/someplace. Saber + de + some skill = to have that skill (example: saber de carpintería = to have knowledge or skills on carpentry).

Comment: @BlasSoriano. First thanks for the reply. Second There's nothing wrong about Diegos ans.

Answer (score 4):

When used with nouns, the distinction is actually deceptively simple.  With *saber*, we refer to concrete data *about* something.  In essence, we refer to the *attributes* of some thing.  Let's say we want to talk about a book:

- Sé el título <sub>(del libro)</sub>
- Sé el lugar de publicación <sub>(del libro)</sub>
- Sé la editorial <sub>(del libro)</sub>
- Sé el tema <sub>(del libro)</sub>
- Sé el color <sub>(del libro)</sub>

All of these attributes fit nicely in questions in the format *¿Cuál es el<sub>/la</sub> ______ del libro?*.  But in this same context, we can't say *sé el libro*.  The book isn't an attribute of something else<sup>1</sup>.

When we want to refer to the thing itself, rather than the *individual* facts/data about it, we use *conocer* which instead of fitting a question like *¿Cuál es el<sub>/la</sub> ______ de ______?* instead answers *¿Cómo es _____*?  This then expresses knowledge of *all* the attributes of the thing simultaneously.

For an example of how this plays out in some of the cases where their usage seems to overlap:

- *¿**Sabes** el precio de las manzanas?*
  Here, the thing in question are the apples, and we want to know if you know a literal fact about them — their price.  The answer would be a single datum, like $2/kg.
- *¿**Conoces** el precio de las manzanas?*
  Here we want to know if you know *cómo es el precio*.  While that could indeed include the current price, it also includes things like its normal variation, whether that price is higher or lower than normal.
- *¿**Sabes** <sub>(el nombre de)</sub> la capital de Canadá?*
  Topic: Canada.  Just give me the answer. *Sí, sé <sub>(el nombre de)</sub> la capital.*  Notice the possibility for an implied *el nombre de*, though its not strictly required.
- *¿**Conoces** la capital de Canadá?*
  Topic: Ottawa.  Are you familiar with the city of Ottawa?

This is why with people you almost always use *conocer* (besides its *to meet* meaning) with people — people are inevitably asking if you know the person *and* their corresponding attributes.  Rarely is the person himself an attribute of something else, but it's not impossible and then we switch to *saber*: *¿Sabes el presidente de Guatemala? Es el Gen. Pérez Molino.*

---

<sup>1.  Note that I refer to *this* context.  The book maybe indeed be an attribute of something else in a different context, for example, the first book published by an author (in which case it becomes an attribute of the author).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Although they are usually words that can not be replaced each other, I think that in the following examples are equivalent sentences.

> Quisiera conocer tu nombre.
>
> Quisiera saber tu nombre.
>
> Ya conoces las reglas del juego.
>
> Ya sabes las reglas del juego.
>
> Conozco algunos datos que te pueden interesar.
>
> Sé algunos datos que te pueden interesar.
>
> Él sabe los precios.
>
> Él conoce los precios.

I feel any difference as a user of the language, but I can not specifically recognize it. In the first instance I think the words are interchangeable when informed "abstract data".